# Data Web Controls Display Value vs Insert ID (foreign key) for Stored Procedures

Tags: asp.net, foreign-keys, sqldatasource, web-controls

I've got a series of comboboxes made from ASP.NET DropDownLists (populated from a select command from an SqlDataSource by DataSourceID), and <input> element, and the jQueryUI autocomplete plugin. You can ignore the latter two though.

Each of the DropDownList controls represents a particular "User" category and is dynamically populated based on `Users` table for that category. Here's the database structure:

```
Users (ID, Name) -- I use a join to display the Name, but I wish to USE the ID.
Team (ID, Member1, Member2, Member3) --each member is a foreign key to the
                                     --"Users" table and used to populate the
                                     --DropDownLists respectively.
```

**QUESTION**: I need to know how to display the `Name` field in the control, but actually use the `ID` of the selected value as the input to my stored procedure.

- additionally, it would be nice to use a single query and SqlDataSource to populate all the drop-downs. Currently I'm using a separate 'select' statement for each of 13 user categories I have.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> additionally, it would be nice to use a single query and SqlDataSource
>   to populate all the drop-downs. Currently I'm using a separate
>   'select' statement for each of 13 user categories I have.

Unfortunately, you have to use separate datasources as there's no support for this if you use SQLDataSource.

In order to Use the ID of the user, set the `DataValueField` to `ID` (assuming that the column name is ID, as you indicated)

In order to display the Name of the user, set the `DataTextField` to `Name` (assuming that the column name is Name, as you indicated)

Therefore, the DropDownList should look like this:

```
<asp:dropdownList id="your_id" DataTextField="Name" 
DataSourceID="YourSqlDataSourceID" DataValueField="ID" runat="server" />
```

[Linking MSDN Documentation.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.dropdownlist.aspx)

Comment: Thoroughly tested and approved, hehe. Thanks so much :)

Comment: On a side note, I'm experimenting with using a single SqlDataSource, and parsing out a 'union all' of all the queries into separate DataTables. Not sure if it's possible or smart, but I'm still learning :)